# UpdateLayeredWindow returns code 6 (ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE)

Tags: winapi, rust

I'm trying to make a fully transparent window with winapi to later serve as an overlay. It seems to work as far as creating window and registering the class goes, but the `UpdateLayeredWindow` function seems to have issues with the window handle as `GetLastError` returns code 6. I'm not sure what exactly causes it.

Without Updating window appears, is interactable, and works ok. After my attempt to update it, it disappears (not transparent though, since events pass to the desktop), and I get error 6.

A puzzling thing is that I still get the messages as the loop doesn't stop until I force quit the process.

```rust
#![windows_subsystem = "windows"]

use kernel32::{GetLastError, GetModuleHandleW};
use std::ffi::OsStr;
use std::iter::once;
use std::os::windows::ffi::OsStrExt;
use std::ptr;
use std::ptr::{null, null_mut};
use user32::CreateWindowExW;
use winapi::shared::minwindef::{HINSTANCE, LPARAM, LRESULT, UINT, WPARAM};
use winapi::shared::windef::{HDC__, HWND, HWND__, POINT, SIZE};
use winapi::um::wingdi::{
    CreateCompatibleDC, DeleteDC, AC_SRC_ALPHA, AC_SRC_OVER, BLENDFUNCTION, RGB,
};
use winapi::um::winuser::{
    DefWindowProcW, DispatchMessageW, GetDC, GetMessageW, RegisterClassW, ReleaseDC,
    TranslateMessage, UpdateLayeredWindow, CS_HREDRAW, CS_OWNDC, CS_VREDRAW, CW_USEDEFAULT, MSG,
    ULW_COLORKEY, WNDCLASSW, WS_EX_LAYERED, WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW, WS_OVERLAPPED, WS_VISIBLE,
};

fn win32_string(value: &str) -> Vec<u16> {
    OsStr::new(value).encode_wide().chain(once(0)).collect()
}

struct BasicWindow {
    window_class: WNDCLASSW,
    window_handle: *mut HWND__,
    mem_DC: Option<*mut HDC__>,
    screen_DC: Option<*mut HDC__>,
}

impl BasicWindow {
    fn new(class_name: String, window_name: String) -> Self {
        unsafe {
            let hinstance = GetModuleHandleW(null_mut());
            let wnd_class = WNDCLASSW {
                style: CS_HREDRAW | CS_OWNDC | CS_VREDRAW,
                lpfnWndProc: Some(DefWindowProcW),
                hInstance: hinstance as HINSTANCE,
                lpszClassName: win32_string(&class_name).as_ptr(),
                cbClsExtra: 0,
                cbWndExtra: 0,
                hIcon: null_mut(),
                hCursor: null_mut(),
                hbrBackground: null_mut(),
                lpszMenuName: null_mut(),
            };

            let atom = RegisterClassW(&wnd_class);

            let handle: *mut HWND__ = CreateWindowExW(
                WS_EX_LAYERED | WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW,
                win32_string(&class_name).as_ptr(),
                win32_string(&window_name).as_ptr(),
                WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_VISIBLE,
                0,
                0,
                1920,
                1080,
                null_mut(),
                null_mut(),
                hinstance,
                null_mut(),
            ) as *mut HWND__;

            println!("handle: {:?}", handle);

            return Self {
                window_class: wnd_class,
                window_handle: handle,
                mem_DC: None,
                screen_DC: None,
            };
        }
    }

    pub unsafe fn make_transparent(&mut self) {
        self.screen_DC = Some(GetDC(null_mut()));
        self.mem_DC = Some(CreateCompatibleDC(GetDC(self.window_handle))); //Some(CreateCompatibleDC(self.screen_DC.unwrap()));

        let mut blend_s = BLENDFUNCTION {
            BlendOp: AC_SRC_OVER,
            BlendFlags: 0,
            SourceConstantAlpha: 255,
            AlphaFormat: AC_SRC_ALPHA,
        };

        let outcome = UpdateLayeredWindow(
            self.window_handle,
            self.screen_DC.unwrap(),
            &mut POINT { x: 0, y: 0 },
            &mut SIZE { cx: 1920, cy: 1080 },
            self.mem_DC.unwrap(),
            &mut POINT { x: 0, y: 0 },
            RGB(255, 255, 255),
            &mut blend_s,
            ULW_COLORKEY,
        );

        println!("outcome: {:?}", outcome);
        println!("err was: {:?}", GetLastError());
    }

    // pub unsafe fn event_job(hWnd: HWND__, Msg: UINT, wParam: WPARAM, lParam: LPARAM) -> LRESULT {
    //
    // }
}

fn main() {
    let mut win: BasicWindow = BasicWindow::new("hewwo".to_owned(), "UwU".to_owned());

    unsafe {
        win.make_transparent();
        loop {
            let mut msg: MSG = std::mem::uninitialized();
            if GetMessageW(&mut msg as *mut MSG, win.window_handle, 0, 0).is_positive() {
                TranslateMessage(&msg as *const MSG);
                DispatchMessageW(&msg as *const MSG);
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }

        match win.mem_DC {
            Some(mut hDC) => {
                println!("releasing mem_dc with outcome: {:?}", DeleteDC(hDC));
                println!(
                    "releasing screen_dc with outcome: {:?}",
                    ReleaseDC(win.window_handle, win.screen_DC.unwrap())
                );
            }
            _ => {}
        }
    }
}
```

Cargo.toml:

```
[package]
name = "catso"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["HerbyBoi <grassyZest@gmail.com>"]
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
winapi = "0.3.9"
widestring = "0.4.3"
user32-sys = "0.2.0"
kernel32-sys="0.2.2"

[features]
default=["winapi/winuser","winapi/minwindef","winapi/windef","winapi/wingdi"]
```

Comment: The DC you're updating your window from (`mem_DC`) doesn't have a 32 bpp bitmap selected into it. `CreateCompatibleDC` leaves you with a 1x1x1 bitmap and you need to create your own bitmap and select it in. But if you're using a color key you don't need `UpdateLayeredWindow` anyway, you can use `SetLayeredWindowAttributes` instead.

Comment: @JonathanPotter but i thought if I created from the DC of window before update then it clones its bitmap?

Comment: Unrelated to your issue, you should probably use the *windows* crate, rather than *winapi*. The latter is dead, and has been so for 2 years. Time to move one. If you do want to use *winapi* make sure to read its [FAQ](https://crates.io/crates/winapi): *"Should I still use those `-sys` crates such as `kernel32-sys`? No."*